# just did a host header change > user profile pics links back to old url

Tags: user-profile

I changed the "my site host" for user profile to the new host header. I reset index, crawl people. people result works but the pic link back to old header so they are not appearing.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Run a full sync of the User Profile Sync, may be one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I did a full sync and that would not work. As the pictures have hardcoded link attached to them. so I following Eric Fang blog http://fangdahai.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-change-my-site-host-url.html
2. Powershell changed the old url to new url
3. I reset the index
4. Ran a full Sync
5. Did a crawl

It worked but the picture would not show up right away. I waited few hours and all seems to be working.

Thanks Benny and Eric...